# combine sets of values into melted format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three set of values contained in `GG` `CC` `TTT`
I would like to make a boxplot of these three sets in a facet_grid. I don't know how to convert this into a melted form column wise.

```
 > GG
 [1]  1.3813117  1.5163896  0.8453227  0.9759973  1.2785990  1.1531961  0.6262850  0.9461095 -0.6565960  0.5073075
[11] -0.5743223  0.8198548 -0.8382672 -0.8611467  0.8043137 -0.4957297 -0.4407040  0.5400756
> CC
[1]  1.9218347  1.3246420 -1.2941452 -0.8447140 -0.8006692  0.9272802  0.9116373  0.5005044
> TTT
 [1]  1.1537972 -1.3378830 -1.4823257  1.1091238  1.2039213  1.3535458 -0.7855620  1.3526200  1.0546998 -1.1473508
[11]  0.9604922  1.2368439  0.8762957  1.0700588 -1.0390931  1.0316614  0.9468012  0.6362604  0.9870086 -0.7457397
[21]  0.9022420 -0.8685273  0.8720614  1.0322280  0.4624016 -0.8120936  0.3801744 -0.7628217 -0.6289436  0.6722584
[31] -0.5488791  0.6531975 -0.5396668  0.5503613 -0.7208796  0.6721789  0.5905945  0.6541330 -0.5690710  0.5785989
[41]  0.5545739  0.5375973  0.2840381
```

Comment: Place it in a `list` and do `boxplot` i.e `boxplot(list(GG, CC, TTT))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create some fake-data vectors
set.seed(195)
GG = rnorm(30)
CC = rnorm(20)
TTT = rnorm(50)

# Combine into a data frame
df = data.frame(source=rep(c("GG","CC","TTT"), sapply(list(GG,CC,TTT), length)),
                values=c(GG,CC,TTT))

ggplot(df, aes(source, values)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

You don't need facets here, but, if desired, you can facet as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes("", values)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(. ~ source) +
  labs(x="")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can place it in a `list` and use `boxplot` from `base R`

```
boxplot(list(GG, CC, TTT))
```

---

Or using `ggplot2` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
melt(mget(c("GG", "CC", "TTT"))) %>%
         ggplot(., aes(x=L1, y=value))+
                          geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: I would like to use ggplot